# Labels on d3.js time series chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been working on a d3.js time series line chart.

I am using `d3.nest` and then looping through the nested groups to create each line.

The complete code [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/christophergandrud/9651e1e6e5f97b9af970)

What I would like to do is have each line's label (the country name) show up on the y-axis at the position of the last observation (given by `credit`). To find this position I use:

```
dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
    var position = d.values[6].credit;
    console.log("Selected Value", position);
```

Then later pass `position` to `.attr("y", y(position))` when I append the text.

The issue I'm having is that the position returned from `d.values[6].credit` is correct as logged in the console. But I get an

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'credit' of undefined
```

error. This leads to the axes not being plotted.

(Eventually I want the labels to appear on `mouseover`, but that is for another day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slovak Republic only has 2 data points:

```
Slovak Republic,SK,Jan 2007,100
Slovak Republic,SK,Jan 2008,105.2
```

Instead of the hard-coded 6, just use:

```
var position = d.values[d.values.length-1].credit;
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uRpPK5R4W2hCfa3M9kxc?p=preview).

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Mind if I ask if you have any thoughts about having the text show only on mouseover?

Comment: @ChristopherGandrud, here's how [I would do it](http://plnkr.co/edit/kBTSssK522SXPkNU4SU5?p=preview).